# Multiple Replacement Rules in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, replace

In SQL Server, let's say I have a query that has a cell with the value 'A,B,C'. In a select statement, I want to do a replacement using the following table.

```
Old | New
---------
 A  |  D
 C  |  F
```

It should return 'D,B,F'. How would I go about doing this? Is there a way to loop REPLACE() in a select statement?

Comment: in oracle this can be achieved using translate function and there is no corresponding inbuilt function in sql- server but user-defined function dbo.translate to mimic the same functionality is available  check this link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic124618-169-1.aspx

Comment: This solved my issue.